# i3 fully nested windows

Tags: window-manager, i3

Is it possible to fully nest or stack a window within another window with a tiling window manager.
The goal is to have window 1 be 'wrapper' so to speak around another window.

Window 2 is running a GUI application that takes up the entire window

Window 1 is running a GUI application that has a blank spot in the middle the same size as window 2, creating a kind of picture in picture effect similar to dragging a window on top of another in a standard DE.

[image: example]

Comment: You can normal drag window 2 to that position and size it, right. That is the result you will get with any program anyway. It also means that unless you give Window 2 an always-ontop setting, switching to window 1 will hide window 2. So is it just that you want to quickly get window 2 in position? or am I missing something here? Also, moving window 1 will not move window 2. If you want window 2 to be affected by window 1, consider something like a VM. Then the app of window 2 will literally be inside window 1.

Comment: Well I am still trying to figure out i3, so I am not sure how I would go about setting a floating window, on top of a full screen tile, and having it stay there consistently (not being dragged around by accidental mouse clicks.)

Ideally window 2 would be 'locked' in place floating inside window 1

Comment: I don't have experience with i3 myself. In fact, I didn't even know what it was, so I updated the tag so it makes sense now. I use ActualTools Window Manager myself, which would be able to define a position on screen and fixate it to those dimensions, resizing the window if possible and necessary. You can then not move the window from that position, and you can set it to always be on top.